# Magento Payment Gateway / Refund Online

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to implement a payment gateway with an online refund.
in the model i have

```
protected $_canCapture = true;
protected $_canRefund = true;

public function capture(Varien_Object $payment, $amount) {
    ....
    return $this;
}

public function refund(Varien_Object $payment, $amount) {
    ....
    return $this;
}
```

It is capturing the payment fine, however when i go into the invoice and credit memo, i can only refund offline.

Does anyone know what else I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the refund online to work, the capture method needs to set a payment ID simply

```
$payment->setTransactionId($api->getPaymentId());
    $payment->setParentTransactionId($payment->getTransactionId());
    $transaction = $payment->addTransaction(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction::TYPE_AUTH, null, true, ""
    );
    $transaction->setIsClosed(true);
```

Then the refund online works and the refund() method is called

Comment: does this makes the refund works with customer payment method also ?